# How to disable tabs in JqGrid at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

**Two Default Grids Defenition:**

```
initialise(){
$("#ExpenseTable").jqGrid({
    datatype : "local",
    mtype : 'GET',
    colModel : [ {name:'expnsId',label:'ID', width:150 }, 
                 {name:'userName',label:'NAME', width:150 },
                 {name:'catName',label:'CATEGORY', width:150 },
                 {name:'date',label:'DATE', width:150 },
                 {name:'amount',label:'AMOUNT', width:150 },
                 {name:'status',label:'STATUS', width:150 }],
    pager : '#ExpPager',
    rowNum : 10,
    rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
    sortname : 'invid',
    sortorder : 'desc',
    viewrecords : true,
    autowidth : false,
    caption : 'Expenses Details',
    onSelectRow : function(expnsId) { dispExpensData(expnsId); }
    }); 
$("#tabs").tabs();
getTokens();//Gets the tokens for the logged in user.
refreshExpenseGrid();//Populates data to the grid
dispLeaveGrid();// It ll call the next default grid
 }
 }

$("#LeaveTable").jqGrid({
    datatype : "local",
    mtype : 'GET',
    colModel : [ {name:'leaveId',label:'ID', width:150 }, 
                 {name:'userName',label:'NAME', width:150 },
                 {name:'fdate',label:'DATE', width:150 },
                         {name:'tdate',label:'DATE', width:150 }
                 {name:'status',label:'STATUS', width:150 }],
    pager : '#ExpPager',
    rowNum : 10,
    rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
    sortname : 'invid',
    sortorder : 'desc',
    viewrecords : true,
    autowidth : false,
    caption : 'Leave Applications',
    onSelectRow : function(leaveId) { displeaveData(leaveId); }
    }); 
refreshLeaveGrid();//Populates data to the grid
securedUI();//This ll call the below function, to check whether the remaining tabs can be visible or not
```

**Secured UI Function:**

```
function securedUI(){


var secToken = "DELETEUSER";
if(!checkRoleToken(secToken)){//If users dont have token to delete user, the buttons ll be disabled
    $('#expDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#lveDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#delUser').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#roleDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#tokenDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}


var secToken= "VIEWUSER";
if(checkRoleToken(secToken)){
    showUserdetails();//3rd Grid Defn:Contains the table definition for user grid.
    initialiseRole();//4th Grid Defn: Role grid
    showtokens();//5th Grid Defn: token grid
}
```

**Check Token:**

```
function checkRoleToken(newToken){
for( var i = 0; i<tokens.length; i++ ){
    var token = tokens[i];//Tokens is like cache, which contains all the tokens that are assigned for the current user.
    if(newToken == token.tokenName){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
 }
```

The html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    initialise();
});
</script>
```

The `LeaveTable` is 2nd grid and i have 3 more grids. But i dont want to show them to all of the users, instead admin users should able to see them. Tokens are the key to find the user have the right to do any operation in the Application. Tokens, that are assigned for the user will be loaded to a client-Side Cache like Array `tokens`.

Every function like `ADD`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` & `VIEW` have their tokens at the start of the function that stored in a variable. That token variable will sent to `CheckToken()` as argument. There it will check that token against the token cache. It ll return `true` or `false`. The operation will cancelled or continued according to that result.

In the above code, at the end of the LeaveTable grid defenition, you can see a function call `securedUI();`. Inside that function i am doing two things. 1.Disabling Delete Buttons, 2.Disabling the `3rd`, `4th` & `5th` grids, for those who dont have tokens `DELETEUSER` & `VIEWUSER`.

Actually what i am getting now is, the `3rd`, `4th` & `5th` grids are not getting displayed for those who have token `VIEWUSER`. Look at the functions `securedUI()` & `checkToken()`, what they should do!!! securedUI() have `VIEWUSER` token and the current user also, so the checkToken() should return true, so it should get into the if block and execute the functions calls inside the if block. But its not doing it. I cant able to get any clue about where i am going wrong.

So, i turned on the firebug and checked it step by step. Magically, now its going into the if block and shows the grid for admin users. Now i felt that it worked then i turned turned off the firebug and reloaded the page again. Ooops, again that 3 remaining grids are not displaying. Can you now able to get an idea about my problem!!!

Any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you should just place all your JavaScript code inside of `jQuery(document).ready` handle: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {/* place your code here */});`

If you do use this handle, please post more full code of your example inclusive full HTML code. You can reduce the code example to have example more compact. Important is only that the problem stay in the code and everyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @The question is now updated. I think, it ll make some sense now.

Comment: @NooBDevelopeR: And where is the **full** HTML? Test JSON data would be also helpful to **reproduce** the problem.

Comment: @NooBDevelopeR: Where you have the word *function* before `initialise(){...` or better `var initialise = function() {...`? What means **twice** } after the `dispLeaveGrid();` and the second definition of `$("#ExpenseTable").jqGrid({...`? Where are definition of `refreshExpenseGrid()`, `getTokens` and other function which you use? What you currently posted are code fragments posted together and **NOT** a code which can be used to **reproduce** your problem. If you want than other help you to find an error in your program you should post your program.

Comment: One more important problem. You forget comma after `{name:'tdate',label:'DATE', width:150 }` in the second definition of `$("#ExpenseTable").jqGrid({`. I recommend you always verify your javascript code in JSLint: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: @Oleg: I think you didnt understood my question. The code written by me is working perfect. There is no syntax or logical errors. The `LeaveTable` is a 2nd grid and i have 3 more grids. But i dont want to show them to all of the users, instead admin users can able to see them. Tokens are the key to find the users have admin rights or not. In the above code, at the end of the `LeaveTable` grid defenition, you can see a function call `securedUI();`. Inside that function i am doing two things. `1`.Disabling Delete Buttons, `2`.Disabling the 3rd, 4th & 5th grids(contd, in the next comment.)

Comment: (Contnd from above comment), for those who dont have tokens `DELETEUSER` & `VIEWUSER`. Actually what i am getting now is, the remaining grids are not getting displayed for those who have token `VIEWUSER`. Look at the functions `securedUI()` & `checkToken()`, what they should do!!! `securedUI()` have `VIEWUSER` token, so the `checkToken()` should return `true`, so it should get into the if block and execute the functions calls inside the if block. But its not doing it. I cant able to get any clue about where i am going wrong. (Contd...)

Comment: (Contnd from above comment): So, i turned on the firebug and checked it step by step. Magically, now its going into the if block and shows the grid for admin users. Now i felt that it worked then i turned turned off the firebug and reloaded the page again. Ooops, again that 3 remaining grids are not displaying. Can you now able to get an idea about my problem!!!

Comment: @NooBDevelopeR: What you wrote is what you **want** that your code do. The code can show what **really** do your program. I asked you to post the HTML code. Why you not want to post it? For example, if your HTML code not started with `<!DOCTYPE ...` statement your code can work very strange. If "The code written by me is working perfect" why you ask the question? So your code has at least one error somewhere. Or the code of jqGrid, jQuery or jQuery UI has a bug. To find an error or a bug one need be able to reproduce the problem. So I can try to help you only it you post enough data for it.

Comment: @NooBDevelopeR: And the code which you posted **do** have syntax errors. For example, look at the `$("#LeaveTable").jqGrid` definition. You can see in `colModel` two objects `{name:'tdate',label:'DATE', width:150 }` and `{name:'status',label:'STATUS', width:150 }` which are **not separated with comma**. This is **a syntax error** in JavaScript.

Comment: @Oleg: Actually, i was a typho error. I copied and pasted the `ExpTable` Definition 2 times and edited the columns and other things as in the `LeaveTable` definition. I for got to remove the comma. Sorry for making confusion. Now the `LeaveTable` definition exactly looks like as in the source code.